# Mistake in %Y %U %u format in R

Tags: r, date-formatting

I have data that is stored in week and weekdays rather than actual dates. Luckily R has formats but  am running into some issues.

Let's take week 8 of 2022 as an example. The week starts at 2022-02-21 and ends at 2022-02-27.

Now in R:

```
format(as.Date("2022-02-21"), format = "%Y %U %u")
[1] "2022 08 1"

format(as.Date("2022-02-26"), format = "%Y %U %u")
[1] "2022 08 6"
```

all of this makes sense so far. However when I try for the Sunday it shows me this:

```
format(as.Date("2022-02-27"), format = "%Y %U %u")
[1] "2022 09 7"
```

It is as if %U starts the week at Sunday whilst %u starts the week at Monday. Am I using the wrong format?

Comment: This is correct. `%U` gives the week which starts on Sunday and `%u` gives the weekday from 1 to 7 where Monday is `1`. There is also `%W` which returns the week which starts on Monday and `%w` which returns the weekday from 0 to 6 with Monday being `0`.

Comment: The `?strptime` help page makes it clear that `%U %u` is inconsistent.  What do you want the results to be?  Should Sunday be day 0 or day 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your week starts on Monday then you might be looking for:

```r
format(as.Date("2022-02-27"), format = "%Y %W %u")
#> "2022 08 7"
```

`%U` returns the week starting on Sunday and `%u` returns the weekday from `1` to `7` where Monday is `1`. `%W` returns the week starting on Monday and `%w` returns the weekday from `0` to `6` with Sunday being `0`.

Comment: Thank you. `%W` is indeed what I was looking for. As @user2554330 said, %w is 0 to 6 starting on Sunday. At least on my device. If you could edit that I can accept your answer

Comment: @WietsedeVries: Sorry I mixed up Monday and Sunday and correct it now. It is actually quite confusing :)